# Maps not working in IOS 4.2

Tags: iphone, ios4

I made one app in IOS4.0 which is working fine. but now i upgraded to IOS 4.2, and now the maps annotations are not showing. But its working absolutely fine on IOS 4.0.

the breakpoint is not coming to the third line of code given below i.e. "MKPinAnnotationView *view;".

```
-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>) annotation
{
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
        return nil;

    MKPinAnnotationView *view;
```

Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What code do you have after that line?

Comment: is it because its going to the 2nd line of code?

Answer (score 0):

Why you are using these lines of code in Annotation

if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])

```
    return nil;
```

Your breakpoint is not coming to the third line just because it simply return by nil

Comment: With this function I am creating annotations of custom class. If i run on IOS 4.0 it returns nil for just userlocation but it goes further to put other annotations. But If i use IOS4.2 it returns nil for userlocation and never comes on the function again to load other annotations. Its very weird situation.

Comment: After the thirdt line of code i am creating annotations....given below are lines   view = [mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"ParkPlaceMark"];   if(!view)
 {
view=[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"ParkPlaceMark"];